# MonoGame 3.6: Direct3D Shader/Effect works on Windows 7 but not Windows 10

Tags: windows, shader, monogame, direct3d, effect

I've got a small test program using a MonoGame 3.6 Direct3D shader/effect that displays an Earth model with continents shaded with a day/night texture (city lights show on the dark side).

https://github.com/davidsummers/mgtest

It works great on Windows 7 but not on Windows 10 Pro.  On Windows 10 Pro it doesn't give any errors but just displays a black ball.

I've been trying to figure out for the last week what might cause it to work correctly on Windows 7 but not Windows 10 Pro.

I've also opened a bug report at https://github.com/MonoGame/MonoGame/issues/6171 with only 1 response so far with someone verifying that it just displays a black ball for them as well.

My understanding is that there *should* be no differences between Windows 7 and Windows 10 Direct3D that would prevent Direct3D from working.  Is this the case or is there something I should do to update code that would make it work on both Windows 7 and Windows 10?

I'm fairly new at shaders/effects so there might be something obvious to someone else that I'm not knowledgeable about yet.

I'm running this on a Dell Precision M6700 with Nvidia Quadro K3000M card with Windows 10 Pro that previously was running Windows 7 Pro and displayed the earth/continents/NightDay Shader/effect with no problems.

The program still works correctly on another box with Windows 7 Pro.

The main question with respect to this issue is: SHOULD a MonoGame 3.6 custom effect/shader that works with Direct3D 9 on Windows 7 work on Windows 10 without any changes?

If not, what changes would need to be made to get it to work?

If it should work, why is not working?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue.  A kind user on GitHub showed me that I had two data structures that should have been the same that weren't the same.

I deleted one of them and changed one of the shader subroutines to use the other data structure.

I also found that some (additional) lighting variables in the shader were not being initialized.

Once I did both of these things then the program seems to work correctly on all platforms.